# Get subfolders from folder with multiple levels

Tags: javascript, directory, subdirectory

I have code which checks all the files in subfolders for a folder. But how can I change it to not only check on subfolder level but also the subfolders of the subfolder and so on?

This is the code i have for the folder and its subfolders:

```
            var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            fso = fso.getFolder(path);
            var subfolders = new Object();
            subfolders = fso.SubFolders;
            var oEnumerator = new Enumerator(subfolders);
            for (;!oEnumerator.atEnd(); oEnumerator.moveNext())
            {
                var itemsFolder = oEnumerator.item().Files;
                var oEnumerator2 = new Enumerator(itemsFolder);
                var clientFileName = null;

                for(;!oEnumerator2.atEnd(); oEnumerator2.moveNext())
                {
                    var item = oEnumerator2.item();
                    var itemName = item.Name;
                    var checkFile = itemName.substring(itemName.length - 3);
                    if(checkFile == ".ac")
                    {
                        var clientFileName = itemName;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

On each level of subfolders I need to check all the files if it can find a .ac file.

Comment: Create a recursive function that checks for the file and then calls itself for all sub folders. (By the way: `itemName.substring(itemName.length - 3)` might produce an error for files with names shorter than 3 characters)

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I mentioned in my comment would look something like this (I don't know much about ActiveX, so there are a lot of comments so hopefully you can easily correct any mistakes):

```
//this is the function that looks for the file inside a folder.
//if it's not there, it looks in every sub-folder by calling itself
function getClientFileName(folder) {
    //get all the files in this folder
    var files = folder.Files;
    //create an enumerator to check all the files
    var enumerator = new Enumerator(files);
    for(;!enumerator.atEnd(); enumerator.moveNext()) {
        //get the file name we're about to check
        var file = enumerator.item().Name;
        //if the file name is too short skip this one
        if (file.length<3) continue;
        //check if this file's name matches, if it does, return it
        if (file.substring(file.length - 3)==".ac") return file;
    }
    //if we finished this loop, then the file was not inside the folder
    //so we check all the sub folders
    var subFolders = folder.SubFolders;
    //create an enumerator to check all sub folders
    enumerator = new Enumerator(subFolders);
    for(;!enumerator.atEnd(); enumerator.moveNext()) {
        //get the sub folder we're about to check
        var subFolder = enumerator.item();
        //try to find the file in this sub folder
        var fileName = getClientFileName(subFolder);
        //if it was inside the sub folder, return it right away
        if (fileName!=null) return fileName;
    }
    //if we get this far, we did not find the file in this folder
    return null;
}
```

You would then call this function like so:

```
var theFileYouAreLookingFor = getClientFileName(theFolderYouWantToStartLookingIn);
```

Again, beware of the above code: I did not test it, nor do I know much about ActiveX, I merely took your code and changed it so it *should* look in all the sub folders.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a recursive function. Here's a simple recursive function that iterates thru each file in the provided path, and then makes a recursive call to iterate thru each of the subfolders files. For each file encountered, this function invokes a provided callback (which is where you'd do any of your processing logic).

Function:

```
function iterateFiles(path, recursive, actionPerFileCallback){ 
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); 
    //Get current folder
    folderObj = fso.GetFolder(path);

    //Iterate thru files in thisFolder
    for(var fileEnum = new Enumerator(folderObj.Files); !fileEnum.atEnd(); fileEnum.moveNext()){
      //Get current file
      var fileObj = fso.GetFile(fileEnum.item());

      //Invoke provided perFile callback and pass the current file object
      actionPerFileCallback(fileObj);
    }

    //Recurse thru subfolders
    if(recursive){
      //Step into each sub folder
      for(var subFolderEnum = new Enumerator(folderObj.SubFolders); !subFolderEnum.atEnd(); subFolderEnum.moveNext()){
          var subFolderObj = fso.GetFolder(subFolderEnum.item());

          //Make recursive call
          iterateFiles(subFolderObj.Path, true, actionPerFileCallback);
        }   
    }
};
```

Usage (here I'm passing in an anonymous function that get's called for each file):

```
iterateFiles(pathToFolder, true, function(fileObj){
    Wscript.Echo("File Name: " + fileObj.Name); 
};
```

Now.. That is a pretty basic example. Below is a more complex implementation of a similar function. In this function, we can recursively iterate thru each file as before. However, now the caller may provide a 'calling context' to the function which is in turn passed back to the callback. This can be powerful as now the caller has the ability to use previous information from it's own closure. Additionally, I provide the caller an opportunity to update the calling context at each recursive level. For my specific needs when designing this function, it was necessary to provide the option of checking to see if each callback function was successful or not. So, you'll see checks for that in this function. I also include the option to perform a callback for each folder that is encountered.

More Complex Function:

```
function iterateFiles(path, recursive, actionPerFileCallback, actionPerFolderCallback, useFnReturnValue, callingContext, updateContextFn){ 
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); 
    //If 'useFnReturnValue' is true, then iterateFiles() should return false IFF a callback fails. 
    //This function simply tests that case.
    var failOnCallbackResult = function(cbResult){
        return !cbResult && useFnReturnValue;
    }

    //Context that is passed to each callback
    var context = {};

    //Handle inputs
    if(callingContext != null){
        context.callingContext = callingContext;
    }

    //Get current folder
    context.folderObj = fso.GetFolder(path);

    //Do actionPerFolder callback if provided
    if(actionPerFolderCallback != null){
        var cbResult = Boolean(actionPerFolderCallback(context));
        if (failOnCallbackResult(cbResult)){
            return false;
        }
    }

    //Iterate thru files in thisFolder
    for(var fileEnum = new Enumerator(context.folderObj.Files); !fileEnum.atEnd(); fileEnum.moveNext()){
        //Get current file
        context.fileObj = fso.GetFile(fileEnum.item());

        //Invoke provided perFile callback function with current context
        var cbResult = Boolean(actionPerFileCallback(context));
        if (failOnCallbackResult(cbResult)){
            return false;
        }
     }

     //Recurse thru subfolders
     if(recursive){
         //Step into sub folder
         for(var subFolderEnum = new Enumerator(context.folderObj.SubFolders); !subFolderEnum.atEnd(); subFolderEnum.moveNext()){
             var subFolderObj = fso.GetFolder(subFolderEnum.item());

             //New calling context that will be passed into recursive call
             var newCallingContext;

             //Provide caller a chance to update the calling context with the new subfolder before making the recursive call
             if(updateContextFn != null){
                 newCallingContext = updateContextFn(subFolderObj, callingContext); 
             }

             //Make recursive call
             var cbResult = iterateFiles(subFolderObj.Path, true, actionPerFileCallback, actionPerFolderCallback, useFnReturnValue, newCallingContext, updateContextFn);
             if (failOnCallbackResult(cbResult)){
                 return false;
             }
         }
     }
     return true; //if we made it here, then all callbacks were successful 
 };
```

Usage:

```
//Note: The 'lib' object used below is just a utility library I'm using.
function copyFolder(fromPath, toPath, overwrite, recursive){

    var actionPerFileCallback = function(context){
        var destinationFolder = context.callingContext.toPath;
        var destinationPath = lib.buildPath([context.callingContext.toPath, context.fileObj.Name]);
        lib.createFolderIfDoesNotExist(destinationFolder);
        return copyFile(context.fileObj.Path, destinationPath, context.callingContext.overwrite);
    };

    var actionPerFolderCallback = function(context){
        var destinationFolder = context.callingContext.toPath;
        return lib.createFolderIfDoesNotExist(destinationFolder);
    };

    var callingContext = {
        fromPath : fromPath,
        toPath : lib.buildPath([toPath, fso.GetFolder(fromPath).Name]), //include folder in copy
        overwrite : overwrite,
        recursive : recursive
    };

    var updateContextFn = function(currentFolderObj, previousCallingContext){
        return {
            fromPath : currentFolderObj.Path,
            toPath : lib.buildPath([previousCallingContext.toPath, currentFolderObj.Name]), 
            overwrite : previousCallingContext.overwrite,
            recursive : previousCallingContext.recursive
        }
    }
    return iterateFiles(fromPath, recursive, actionPerFileCallback, null, true, callingContext, updateContextFn);
};
```

I know this question is old but I stumbled upon it and hopefully my answer will help someone!